# Java Spark: Creation of key vector for aprroxNearestNeighbor in case of categorical data

Tags: apache-spark, nearest-neighbor, apache-spark-ml, lsh

I am trying to find approximate nearest neighbors for a categorical dataset. 
For this, I am using `MinHashLSH` model present in Spark.

My dataset has categorical data. So I am using `StringIndexer` followed by `OneHotEncoderEstimator` followed by `VectorAssembler` to convert the categorical values into continuous values.

Now I want to find nearest neighbors for a given key from my dataset and this key should be in Vector form. I am unable to find a way to convert a categorical key into a continuous vector.

```java
List<Row> dataA = Arrays.asList(RowFactory.create(0, "apple"),
            RowFactory.create(1, "banana"),
            RowFactory.create(2, "coconut"));

StructType schema = new StructType(
            new StructField[] { new StructField("id", DataTypes.IntegerType, false, Metadata.empty()),
                    new StructField("fruits", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()) });
Dataset<Row> dfA = spark.createDataFrame(dataA, schema);
StringIndexer stringIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("fruits").setOutputCol("fruitIndex").setHandleInvalid("keep");
OneHotEncoderEstimator  encoder = new OneHotEncoderEstimator().setInputCols(new String[]{"fruitIndex"}).setOutputCols(new String[]{"fruitVec"});
String[] featuredCols = new String[] {"fruitIndex","fruitVec"};
VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(featuredCols).setOutputCol("features");

Pipeline sovPipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(new PipelineStage[]{stringIndexer, encoder, assembler}); 
    //  Feature Transformation
PipelineModel plModel = sovPipeline.fit(dfA);
Dataset<Row> dfT = plModel.transform(dfA);
MinHashLSH mh = new MinHashLSH().setNumHashTables(5).setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("hashes");
MinHashLSHModel model = mh.fit(dfT);
// model.approxNearestNeighbors(dfT, key, 2).show();
```

How can I create the `key`(numerical continuous vector) for `approxNearestNeighbors` method from a categorical key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Vector` you use should be transformed using the same methods as the training data. Since `Pipeline` model cannot work on single item, the quickest solution is to use a single item `Dataset`:

```java
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector;

Vector key = plModel.transform(spark.createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(
    RowFactory.create(0, "some key")), schema
)).first().getAs("features");
```